# windows memory segmentation & Ollydbg

Tags: windows, ollydbg, memory-segmentation

a few questions about windows memory segmentation.

1. every process in windows got his own virtual memory. does it mean that each  each process has it own task
   (I mean own Task descriptor or Task gate) ?
2. I opened a simple exe with ollydbg and I saw that for each CALL intruction to a dll  function is taking me to the jumping table. the jumping table had jumping instructions to the DLLs like this one :

   JMP DWORD PTR DS:[402058]

   my question is why its  uses the data segment and not the CS selector for the base address?
   if I open the memory map and find what stored at 402058 I find  that it containes resorces.
   if I understand correctly the addresses of the DLL function stored in the DS ?
3. I noticed that the memory map is organized by owner. shouldn't it be organized with segments like all  the code be in  CS data in DS etc ?

   thank you

Answer (score 0):

1.
A `Process` has it's own virtual address space.
I do not understand what you're referring to as "Task descriptor or Task gate", but the Windows operating system holds a descriptor for each process, called the `Process Control Block`, that contains information about the process (such as identification, access tokens, execution state, virtual memory mapping, etc).

A `Task` is a logical unit that can be used to manage a single process, or multiple processes.

Job -> Tasks

Task -> Processes

Process -> Threads

2.
In the case you mentioned, which is common for compilers, the program uses the .DATA section to store the jump table after loading the function addresses.

The reason why this happens in the first place is because the compiler cannot know the DLL base address at compile-time, therefore the address has to be fixed at load-time to point to the function. This is known as Relocation.

In order to maintain the jump table seperately from the code, compilers store it in the .DATA section. This way, we can also give it write permissions (usually the .DATA segment has write permissions) and modify it as necessary without sacrificing stability and security.

3.
Each module loaded in the process' virtual address space contains it's own sections - that's why you see a different set of .text, .data, .reloc etc for each module. The "Owner" column is the module name.

P.S. Please ask one question per post - that way it will be easily accesible by other users after you get answered, and each question will likely get more accurate answers.